# Questão de algoritmo A*

Tags: inteligência-artificial

Olá pessoal estou realizando um lista de exercício sobre busca A* porem não possuo a resposta, gostaria de saber se a minha resposta está correta.

Segue em imagem a questão e a minha resposta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resposta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua pergunta parece legal, mas use texto ao invés de imagens, por favor.