# O que é uma heurística?

Tags: algoritmo, terminologia

É o mesmo que inteligência artificial? Qual a relação entre essas coisas? Por que ela importa para nós programadores? Pode dar uma exemplo para ilustrar?

Comment: Sugestão de adendo: o que difere uma heurística de uma meta-heurística?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239578/%c3%a9-admiss%c3%advel-a-heuristica-hn-0-para-algoritimo-a

Comment: É uma palavra bonita pra "chute" [contém ironia].

Comment: @LINQ ainda bem que você disse porque senão eu teria que usar uma heurística pra descobrir se continha :)

Answer (score 8):

Uma heurística é uma técnica que permite melhorar a eficiência da procura. A palavra se origina do grego "Heuriskein" que significa descobrir, também originada de Eureka que provem da expressão "heurika" que ficou famosa por Arquimedes.

A heurística então será uma estimação adequada do custo ou longitude do passo (no espaço de procura) desde um estado até um objectivo. Dizem que subestima a distância se a sua estimação até o objectivo é menor ou igual a distância real.

Dado a complexibilidade da Heurística então, vamos falar sobre sua relação com a Inteligência Artificial, usada como técnica de busca para a obtenção de metas em problemas não algorítimicos que geram "explosões" combinatórias.

Um dos exemplos mais famosos é o de blocos a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte:

http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~ffaria/ia1s2015/class04/class04a-Buscacominformacao_estrategias.pdf

http://cee.uma.pt/edu/iia/acetatos/iia-Procura%20Informada.pdf

Comment: É sempre positivo por a fonte dos dados, principalmente quando não estás escavando do fundo da memória o conteúdo. Pelo conteúdo, me parece que pesquisaste por cá: http://cee.uma.pt/edu/iia/acetatos/iia-Procura%20Informada.pdf

Comment: Acabei esquecendo, mas já está no tópico as fontes. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Existem problemas na Computação que atualmente são impossíveis de se obter uma solução ótima em tempo polinomial, ou seja, não estaremos vivos quando for terminado o processamento e isso se dá devido ao altíssimo número de possibilidades que são necessárias de serem analisadas que crescem exponencialmente com o número de variáveis. Estes problemas são conhecidos como [NP-Completo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34104/o-que-%C3%A9-um-problema-np-completo). Um exemplo deste tipo de problema é o famoso Caixeiro Viajante, onde dado vários pontos em uma área e vários caminhos conectando estes pontos, é preciso procurar o menor circuito passando por todos os pontos sem repetir nenhum caminho e retornando ao ponto de origem obtendo a menor distância possível. Esta resolução de problema é útil por exemplo para otimizar frotas de entrega de empresas.

Para contornar este problema, ao invés de analisar todas as situações possível, são utilizadas [Heurísticas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heur%C3%ADstica) que podem não dar a melhor solução, mas sim se aproximar dela. No exemplo do Caixeiro Viajante, ao invés de verificarmos todos os caminhos possíveis, podemos adotar a abordagem de um ponto x sempre escolher a menor distância à um outro ponto y até que se volte ao ponto inicial. Nesta abordagem não é garantido que a distância obtida ao final seja a menor distância possível, tendo em vista de a escolha de um caminho menor pode te obrigar a escolher um caminho muito grande no futuro. Entretanto ao se abordar o problema desta forma o tempo para se obter a solução passa a ser polinomial.

Comment: Então o que é exatamente heurística?