# Quantidade de índices influência no desempenho?

Tags: mysql, sql, desempenho, índices

Tenho um banco de dados relativamente grande.

E a consulta nele varia bastante e tenho algumas dúvida com relação a desempenho:

1- Criar vários índices, levando em consideração o

> Where (E.condicao = '1') AND (E.situacao != 'desativado')...

Influencia no desempenho? (Além do espaço em disco?)

2 - Como ele define qual índice usar?

3 - Existe alguma ponderação com relação a utilizar vários índices?

Usando MySQL 5.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1 - Criar vários índices, levando em consideração o

```
Where (E.condicao = '1') AND (E.situacao != 'desativado')...
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Filter.sql).

> Influencia no desempenho? (Além do espaço em disco?)

Acho que foi respondido em [Quais as vantagens e desvantagens do uso de índices em base de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35088/101).

> 2 - Como ele define qual índice usar?

Usando [álgebra relacional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) e [teoria dos conjuntos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory) confrontando com dados concretos e estatísticos da base de dados para obter [heurísticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/357809/101) que determinam que um dos índices existentes produzirá resultado de forma mais eficiente, ou que um índice ser criado só para a operação pode compensar seu custo.

Neste exemplo ele procurará um índice que seja composto pela coluna `condicao` e se possível seguido da coluna `situacao`, que por sinal parece uma coluna ineficiente.

> 3 - Existe alguma ponderação com relação a utilizar vários índices?

Pode ver isso em [Índices desnecessários no banco são um problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23348/101).